# How to get meta property="og:image"

Tags: php, facebook, meta-tags

php file :

```
 $data['listing_cover'] = md5(rand(10000000, 20000000)).'.jpg';
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['listing_cover']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/listing_cover_photo/'.$data['listing_cover']);
```

html file :

```
  <head>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo base_url('uploads/listing_cover_photo/'.$data['listing_cover']); ?>" />
  </head>
```

Error on facebook :

Provided og:image URL, https://eforie.org/uploads/listing_cover_photo/ could not be processed as an image because it has an invalid content type.

Comment: You forget about .jpg

Comment: It sounds like you are creating the Meta tag when someone uploads a file. Facebook will not look at the Meta tag then. Facebook will take the og:url and scrape it later.

Comment: What is the URL you are sharing to Facebook?

Comment: Are you sure you want to apply `base_url` to the path you are creating there?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it is a valid image URL - when i enter the URL in the browser, i get a 403/forbidden error. I must be public too, available to everyone (and Facebook).

Comment: <?php echo base_url('uploads/listing_cover_photo/'.$data['listing_cover']); ?> This is the problem, when someone upload the cover image, the script rename the photo with $data['listing_cover'] = md5(rand(10000000, 20000000)).'.jpg'; .... but the meta property don't take the full url